# how to open avi file in firefox using Window media player

Tags: html

I have problem reguarding .avi file is not open in morzila firefox with window media player

My Code is

```
<html>
 <head>


 </head>
 <body>
<object width="425px" height="360px" >
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<param name="movie" value="video.avi"/>
<embed src="video.avi" width="425" height="360" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"/>
</object>

 </body>
</html>
```

for playing my video 
video play in IE but Cant Play in Morzila Fire fox

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use this `type` : `application/x-shockwave-flash`. It's for `.swf` to make browser load it via the flash player.

Now, if you want to use another player to play avi you could use those type :

- application/x-mplayer2
- video/x-msvideo
- video/avi (not sure about this one)
- video/quicktime (not sure about this one)

More information on the WMP plugin and how to load it (via page source) in [the Plugin Doc of Mozilla](http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/windows.html)

Finally, you're not in the obligation to use WMP plugin and may want to use the new `<video>` tag from html5 or a flash player :

- http://www.html5video.org/
- http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=html5+video